# How to erase a vector element within double for loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, vector, contour

I have a vector of a struct

```
vector<contour> hotspots;
```

contour is a structure i have defined like below

```
struct contour
{
    double arc;
    double area;
    Point2f center;
    double me;
    double hullArea;
    vector<Point> contourVector;
    vector<Point> hullVector;

    bool operator <(const contour& comp)
    {
        return me < comp.me;
    }
};
```

So what I am trying to do is loop through that and remove every contour that is contained within another contour, I can get it working for the most part but I get an index error sometimes and I am assuming it has something to do with when I erase an element the index's get messed up so I go out of range. Here is my loop that I wrote:

```
vector<vector<Point>> cleanUp(vector<Point2f> centers, vector<Moments> areas, vector<vector<Point>> contours)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < contours.size(); j++)
            if (i != j)
            {
                if ((areas[i].m00 < areas[j].m00) == true && (pointPolygonTest(contours[j], centers[i], false) > 0) == true)
                {
                    contours.erase(contours.begin() + i);
                    centers.erase(centers.begin() + i);
                    areas.erase(areas.begin() + i);
                }
            }

    return contours;
}
```

I have tried a few different solutions such as i - 1 but that deletes the wrong contour, and instead of using erase, overwriting the element i want to delete with the last one then using .pop_back to delete the last element but that did not seem to work either. Any ideas?

Edit: Fixed the out of sync issue with the areas and centers, but now the issue shows up right away as soon as I call the function to erase some of the contours.

Comment: Your `areas` and `contours` get "out of sync" after the first deletion. You should either delete things from both of them, or come up with some other way of representing both the area and the contour as a single item.

Comment: God... I didn't even realize I wasn't doing that, I even thought about that when I was planning... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With iterators, I'd try this approach:

```
#include <iterator>

template <typename BinaryPred>
void RemoveIfPairwise(std::vector<T> & v, BinaryPred f)
{
    for (auto it1 = v.begin(); it1 != v.end(); ++it1)
    {
        for (auto it2 = std::next(it1); it2 != v.end(); )
        {
            if (f(*it1, *it2)) { it2 = v.erase(it2); }
            else               { ++it2;              }
        }
    }
}
```

This uses the iterator non-invalidation guarantees of `std::vector`, for instance erasing does not invalidate iterators before the point of erasure (so `it1` needs no special treatment).

Note that this loop only inspects pairs of distinct elements; you need to modify it to also inspect the diagonal.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the diagonal? Thanks.

Comment: I think he means the case of `i == j`.

Comment: `v.erase(it2++);` should be `it2=v.erase(it2);` for 2 reasons I can think of, both UB.  (post increment uses an invalid iterator; and if we advance after erase we can skip end).

Comment: @Yakk: Thank you, very true. I actually made this very mistake just recently in some real code :-S

Comment: @JayBell: Think of your iteration as a square of indexes (i, j). The current loop traverses the strict upper triangle, and the diagonal consists of all pairs (i, i), which in the algorithm amounts to comparing elements with themselves.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I see now, I do not want to compare elements to themselves. Only contours that are contained within other contours. Thank you I will try and understand your code today.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a list of indices for the items to delete and delete the items at those indices at the end.

```
vector<vector<Point>> cleanUp(vector<Point2f> centers,
                              vector<Moments> areas,
                              vector<vector<Point>> contours)
{
   std::<int> itemsToErase;

    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < contours.size(); j++)
            if (i != j)
            {
                if ((areas[i].m00 < areas[j].m00) == true &&
                    (pointPolygonTest(contours[j], centers[i], false) > 0) == true)
                {
                   itemsToErase.push_front(i);
                }
            }

    while  ( !itemsToErase.empty() )
    {
       int i = itemsToErase.back();
       contours.erase(contours.begin() + i);
       centers.erase(centers.begin() + i);
       areas.erase(areas.begin() + i);
       itemsToErase.pop_back();
    }

    return contours;
}
```